# MySQL Connection and Command

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I've seen snippets of code in which a Java servlet initially connects to a MySQL database. In which case it uses the whole Class.forName() method via the JDBC API. But, I've also seen elsewhere that when the servlet connects to the database and executes a command it uses Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command string). These are two completely different methods but both seem to communicate with the database. **Does the latter servlet connect to the database in the same way as the former and I just haven't seen that part of the code? Or, are there just two separate ways for a servlet to communicate with a database? ** Can both methods coincide (one for setup and the other for common commands)? Or, can I run SQL commands with both the JDBC API or Runtime.exec()method as a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example ***used to be*** required for loading a JDBC driver, it isn't since JDBC 4.0; see also the [`DriverManager` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) which says (in part)

> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.

The second example, [`Runtime.exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) (per the linked Javadoc)

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process.

And it isn't limited to running a MySQL command, but I would strongly recommend not using it in server side code (*shudder*).

Comment: Perhaps the OP misses CGI

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must ask why not to use it in server side code, though?

Comment: It executes outside the JVM in a seperate process. What happens if an attacker hits that page with one million requests? What about other possible attack vectors on your server? Can they craft a `String` and execute arbitrary commands? Are you sure?

Comment: Okay thank you! I didn't have that in mind. So, ultimately for learning purposes I must load the drivers at some point in the server to use the DB, but in order to execute a command I have to use the exec() method, correct?

Comment: No. The JDBC driver (as of JDBC 4.0) *registers* itself. And [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is what I prefer (when I need to execute a "command").

Comment: Thanks for everything.